# Is there a way to intercept all network requests made by JavaScript in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch, monkeypatching

F.e., maybe I can monkey patch `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` so that I can change the request. But what if some code is using `window.location`? Can I monkey patch that somehow? What other ways?

Comment: What sort of interactions with `window.location` do you want to intercept?

Comment: A Google Chrome extension can probably do this.  Or are you trying to come up with some kind of browser-agnostic script injection?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was trying to pause any time a script wanted to change the window's URL, but I don't have any idea in the code this is in order to place break points, so I thought maybe it was possible to monkey patch some APIs and place `debugger`s in the monkey patch.

Comment: @DaveS ^ I was trying to do that.

Comment: `window.location` is really strange. It can *act* like a setter/getter, since assigning to it results in the page changing, but getting it results in a Location object. Same for `window.location.href`, and unfortunately, both properties are *nonconfigurable*, which means that changing their (apparent) plain values to JS setters/getters (which would let you observe changes) is impossible, I think. If it was anything other than `window.location`, it'd probably be possible. Maybe attach something to `beforeunload`, see if that can give you the information you want?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I tried `beforeunload`, but unfortunately pausing at a debugger there does not show a relevant stack trace. I wasn't thinking hard enough about it, because I just realized that using `window.location` is different than using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` without changing the current page URL.

Comment: If you want a stack trace, does `console.trace` in `beforeunload` show you anything useful?

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, because it's the same trace I see on the debugger point in Sources tab, out of context from any original code that initiated it.

Comment: Or basically, if some code sets `window.location` that's one stack trace, then at some point later `beforeunload` runs which is a different stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use Service Workers API. Check [Service worker concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) and [Using example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers). Using service workers you can intercept any requests and responses, reject them or pass. Beside that service workers are available throughout different pages, so pages can communicate.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about that, but I wanted to pause script execution to see what the code making the network requests is doing, but I don't know what/where that code is, so I thought I could monkey patch and then stick `debugger`s into the monkey patched APIs which will be called by any scripts.